# Redux : Updating object values inside array immutably

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
const initialState = {
  arr: [
    {
      name: "Chicken",
      grade: "A",
      quantity: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Mutton",
      grade: "B",
      quantity: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Sandwich",
      grade: "A-Plus",
      quantity: 0
    }
  ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        arr: {
          ...state.arr,
          [state.arr[action.index]]: {
            ...state.arr[action.index],
            [state.arr[action.index][0].quantity]:
              [state.arr[action.index][0].quantity] + 1
          }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I'm trying to update the quantity immutably. Each time I click on a button, the quantity should be increased by 1. The above code which I have written is wrong (hence posting the query here). I'd appreciate it if anyone could show me where I went wrong and point me in the right direction.

The final output I am expecting is:

```
arr: [
    {
      name: "Chicken",
      grade: "A",
      quantity: 1   // Updated value
    },
    {
      name: "Mutton",
      grade: "B",
      quantity: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Sandwich",
      grade: "A-Plus",
      quantity: 0
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that won't work with your current code. Your initial state defines `arr` as an Array, but your reducer is returning an Object instead. Also, when you are trying to access the `quantity` key of the object inside `arr`, you are using an additional `[0]` index accessor that doesn't match with your data structure.

I would also suggest that you compose reducers (using [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)), to make it easier for you to keep track of the data structure. Combining reducers lets you handle individual levels of your data structure without having to worry about the whole structure. Also, using the spread operator works well for objects, but functions like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) sometimes are clearer when manipulating arrays.

Something like this would do what you need:

```
const arr = (state = initialState.arr, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_QUANTITY:
            return state.map((element, i) => {
                return i === action.index ? {...element, quantity: element.quantity + 1} : element;
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({arr});
```